# Does std::future support polymorphism?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, future

Does std::future in c++ support polymorphism?
So, if to store `child_class` in `future<parent_class>`, can I after get it after by `dynamic_cast<child_class>`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if you declare a `std::function<T>` where T is a base class and you then put a derived class `D` into it, can you retrieve it and `dynamic_cast` back to `D`?

Comment: @Olipro sry. edited. so, the question is if the std::future of base class store derived class, and after get it value from std::future by dynamic cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing you use a reference or a pointer (probably obvious since it'll fail to compile otherwise)... Yes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
struct Parent {
    virtual void a() { cout << "I am parent"; }
};
struct Child : Parent {
    virtual void a() { cout << "I am child"; }
};

Child g_c; //just some global for the purposes of the example

int main() {
    std::future<Parent&> p = async(launch::async, []() -> Parent& { return g_c; });
    auto c = dynamic_cast<Child&>(p.get());
    c.a();
    return 0;
}
```

code result here: http://ideone.com/4Qmjvc

Comment: I tried to use pointer and shared_ptr with your provided code, and get segmentation fault. T_T

Comment: Well then... share the changed code and we can see what's wrong

Comment: Well, both those are complete garbage because you create the `shared_ptr`/pointer but never actually put a valid object into it. If you actually do that it works fine: http://ideone.com/mtbrCE

Comment: ohh.. my huge mistake. I forgot to initialize. Many thank to you